# Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty}s_n=0$ if and only if $\lim_{n \to \infty}|s_n|=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

First, assume that $\lim s_n=0.$ This implies that  for any given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ an $N$ such that for $n>N,|s_n-0|< \epsilon$.

$|s_n-0|=|s_n|<\epsilon$ and $|s_n|=||s_n|-0| \implies ||s_n|-0|<\epsilon$ which, by the definition of the limit implies $\lim|s_n|=0$.

Is this correct? I am also stuck about how to prove this the other way, i.e. $\lim|s_n|=0 \implies \lim s_n=0$.

Help?

Comment: You have some misunderstanding of the concept of limit. ``... for some small $\varepsilon > 0$ is logically incorrect. Try to restate it. To your question, it is sufficient to note that $$\left|\left|s_n\right|\right| = \left|s_n\right|.$$

Comment: For any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N$ such that for any $n>N$, $|s_n|<\epsilon$. This means that $s_n\rightarrow 0$. Once you get that logic straight, your math is basically correct.

Comment: You should look up the $(\epsilon, \delta)$ definition of a limit to make sure you have everything straight.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit

Comment: @jdods what about the reverse?

Comment: Use the hint in the first comment. There really is little difference in both directions. I'll write it up later for you if no one else does sooner.

Comment: @Zhanxiong: For what it's worth, you can use `$$\left\lVert s_n\right\rVert=\left|s_n|\rvert.$$` to render $$\left\lVert s_n\right\rVert=\left|s_n\right|.$$ Fewer keystrokes, and looks (to my eye, anyway) a bit nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact (as you have) that $\left||s_n|-0\right|=\left||s_n|\right|=\left|s_n\right|=\left|s_n-0\right|$,

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=0$ iff for every $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\ge N\implies\left|s_n-0\right|<\epsilon$

$\hspace{.78 in}$iff for every $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\ge N\implies\left||s_n|-0\right|<\epsilon$

$\hspace{.78 in}$iff $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}|s_n|=0$.